# C# - issue with proxy check

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest

I have been trying to make a simple proxy checker...

```
WebProxy myProxy = default(WebProxy);
foreach (string proxy in Proxies)
{
    try
    {
        myProxy = new WebProxy(proxy);
        HttpWebRequest r = HttpWebRequest.Create("<a href="http://www.google.com"" rel="nofollow">http://www.google.com"</a>);
        r.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36";
        r.Timeout = 3000;
        r.Proxy = myProxy;
        HttpWebResponse re = r.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine($"[+] {proxy} Good", ConsoleColor.Green);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[-] {proxy} Bad", ConsoleColor.Red);
    }
}
```

for some reason this line:

```
HttpWebRequest r = HttpWebRequest.Create("<a href="http://www.google.com"" rel="nofollow">http://www.google.com"</a>);
```

I see a little red line under the http, and this is the error I get

```
The best overload for Create does not have a parameter names http
```

How can I fix it? and I how can I make it check proxies reall fast, not like 1 proxy every 5 seconds

Comment: You don't give HTML to `Create`: you just give the URL.

Comment: if I type only the URL then HttpWebRequest.Create return error

Comment: Hi Alex - @HereticMonkey is correct, and you probably should post a new question regarding the (specific) error you get when you properly send the parameters as they describe.  The issue is that you're trying to provide HTML here, and that is the correct answer.

Comment: The basic issue is you are not properly escaping your string, so it thinks that everything after `"<a href="` is the name of a parameter, which it can't find. The actual issue is that you don't pass HTML to the create function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`HttpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.7.2) class's `Create` method takes the URL as a string, not HTML:

```
HttpWebRequest r = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
```

Since there's actually no `Create` on `HttpWebRequest`, but only on `WebRequest`, your code is most likely actually this:

```
HttpWebRequest r = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
```

But what you want is this:

```
HttpWebRequest r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: I tried that but the problem is that I get another error:
"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.WebRequest' to 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'. An explicit conversion exists"

Comment: oh, thanks but now I have the same problem with this:

HttpWebResponse re = r.GetResponse();

Comment: Well, I've shown you how to cast an object from one type to another. This is where you need to see if you can apply the pattern I've shown here to your other code. If you still have questions, please ask a new question.

Comment: yeah your right, I should try on my own now because I won't learn if I keep asking questions, thank you very much :)

Comment: Sure thing. You might take a look at this help page too :): https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers